# Can I run a specified maven execution from the command line?

Tags: maven

If I configure a maven plugin with a number of executions:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>...</groupId>
      <artifactId>...</artifactId>
      <version>...</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>execution-1</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>...</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
                 ...
          </configuration>
          <phase>...</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>execution-2</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>...</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
                 ...
          </configuration>
          <phase>...</phase>
        </execution>
       </executions>
      <configuration>
            ...
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

can I specify one of these executions to run on the command line (without changing the id to default-cli)?

Comment: I think the answer is *no*, but I'm open to learn something new :) Would you care for profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. See for instance a related [Maven mailing list thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Invoke-a-plugin-from-command-line-and-specifing-an-execution-id-td97166.html)
Basically, executions are to be used inside the lifecycle, not for a single execution.

You should use profiles to achieve what you need.

Comment: Can you give some more detail on how I would use profiles to do this?

Comment: It highly depends on the changes that your different plugin executions require. It might vary from changing a single property inside the different profiles to having a full plugin configuration inside each profile. For the profile usage itself, see the Sonatype Book chapter that explains the concept: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-maven-profiles.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out. I mostly want to do this when I am debugging some new functionality that has been added to a POM, and I want to run just that execution. Profiles might be overkill for this, but I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use profiles to do this.